# Companion objects - does Android want to register them as activities (?)

Tags: android, kotlin, companion-object

I have an Activity

```
class DummyActivity : Activity() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun onNewIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            val intent = Intent(context, DummyActivity.javaClass)
            return intent
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

It is declared in the Manifest as follows:

```
    <activity android:name=".DummyActivity"/>
</application>
```

When I try to launch it, I get:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class > {com.example.andrzejzuzak.visiondummyapp/com.example.andrzejzuzak.visiondummyapp.DummyActivity$Companion}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
>                                                                                                at com.example.andrzejzuzak.visiondummyapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:85)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

What bothers me is this line:

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.andrzejzuzak.visiondummyapp/com.example.andrzejzuzak.visiondummyapp.DummyActivity$Companion

Does it actually mean that I have to register the Companion object somewhere?

Comment: You should use `Intent(context, DummyActivity::class.java)` instead

Comment: Unrelated: Activity already has a `onNewIntent` method, maybe you'd like to rename your factory method to something simple and understandable at first glance like `createIntent`. (It's not a callback, it doesn't start with `on`.) Save your future self some time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DummyActivity.javaClass` refers to `DummyActivity.Companion` and not to `DummyActivity`. In fact, it is even a warning:

> The resulting type of this `javaClass` call is
>   `Class<Dummy.Companion>` and not `Class<Dummy>`. Please use more clear
>   `::class.java` syntax to avoid confusion.

[image: Warning]

Instead, you should use `DummyActivity::class.java`,

Comment: What is @JvmStatic in this case?  And thank you for this answer!

Comment: Just copied the question's code. In short, `@jvmStatic` tells the compiler to make this method static in the JVM platform.

Comment: if @jvmstatic is being used, why is it inside the companion object, isn't the above code saying `onNewIntent()` is a static method of Dummy's internal companion's object rather than a static method of `Dummy`